# How to get additional access tokens from Cordova application without logging in again?

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser, identityserver3

I have a Cordova application that I want to integrate with Identity Server using the implicit flow.  To enable logging in with the redirects to a 3rd party IdentityProvider I used the inAppBrowser and a modified version of the OIDC Token Manager.  The Identity and Access tokens are returned from the inAppBrowser to the Cordova application, however I lose the session with Identity Server that would enable the user to obtain additional access tokens.  Is there a way to use the existing tokens to get additional access tokens from Identity Server without forcing the user to login again?  Or is there another endpoint that I’m missing (something like a Ticket Granting Ticket)?

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

Normally what you would do is keep around the same instance of the in-app browser. That way it can maintain the cookies it's holding and your user can still be logged in if/when you make another authorization request.